# Article margin-top affecting sidebar margin-top

Tags: html, css

I don't want them to be on the same level. They are both independent divs. The sidebar is fixed.
Why doesn't the sidebar stick on top instead of being aligned with the article div ?

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div#sidebar{
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
}

div#article{
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="sidebar">
    sidebar
</div>
<div id="article">
    article
</div>
```

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: Where is your HTML source? What is your question?

Comment: My question is, why doesn't the sidebar stick on top instead of being aligned with the article div ?

Comment: This is not a correct way to ask question. Your question must have all section that users need to understand such as HTML, CSS, Scripts, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this trick : `top:-0px;`. Don't know, but works for some reason!

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div#sidebar{
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top:-0px; /* <-- right here */
}

div#article{
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    sidebar
</div>
<div id="article">
    article
</div>
```